# Flutter. Темы и Стили. Подскажите правильные подходы работы со стилями?

Tags: flutter

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь выработать подход к работе со стилями во Flutter приложении.
Раздражает, например, стилизация во View компонента. Делает его плохо читаемым.
Я понимаю, что в компаниях все разрабатывает дизайнер.
Но все же интересно, какие подходы используете вы?

1. Цвета приложения генерируете из ColorScheme.fromSeed, переопределяете все цвета или переопределяете стили виджетов глобально типа AppBar?
2. Как работаете с виджетами с индивидуальным дизайном, а именно где держите их стили?
   Выносите слили отдельно или храните в компоненте и как именно?
   Может выносите в extentions в тему? Если выносите, то все стили, или только цвета, градиенты и текстовые стили?

Можете расскажите о своих подходах к работе со стилями, которые позволяют делать код более поддерживаемым и расширяемым?

Answer (score 0):

Могу отметить для себя важность и удобство:

- создания мультиязычности (искать flutter_localizations, l10n)
- создания класса для цветов приложения (хранить можно в lib/ui/theme/colors.dart)

  ```
  class AppColors {

   static const Color white = Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1);
   static const Color black = Color.fromRGBO(29, 29, 33, 1);

  }
  ```
- создания темы приложения, которая включает lightTheme, darkTheme (хранить можно в lib/ui/theme/theme.dart)

  ```
  final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
   brightness: Brightness.light,
   primaryColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
   shadowColor: AppColors.primaryColor.withOpacity(0.17),
   dividerColor: AppColors.dividerColor,
   hintColor: AppColors.hintColor,
   errorColor: AppColors.errorColor,
   dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
   disabledColor: AppColors.disabledColor,
   buttonTheme: buttonTheme,
   inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationTheme,
   textTheme: textTheme,
   fontFamily: 'Montserrat');



  final TextTheme textTheme = TextTheme(
   headline1: const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 24,
   ),
   headline2: const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 20,
   ),
  );

  // buttonTheme и inputDecorationTheme по такому же смыслу
  ```

Пример использования темы (также видно локализацию):

```
return MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          theme: themeProvider.isDarkTheme ? darkTheme() : lightTheme(),
          supportedLocales: l10n.all,
           localizationsDelegates: const [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
           ],
          initialRoute: RouteNames.splashScreen,
          routes: _router.routes,
        );
```

Касательно виджетов с индивидуальным дизайном, если верно понял, то вот пример хранения виджета (lib/ui/widgets/button.dart):

```
class AppButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? child;
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  final Color? color;

  const AppButton({Key? key, this.child, this.onPressed, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              10),
        ),
        backgroundColor: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
        shadowColor: AppColors.shadowColor,
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```